# AngularJS $location replace() replacing last history entry also

Tags: angularjs, html5-history

On my AngularJS application I need to save only state changes in the browser history. That's why when I'm changing parameters of $location, I'm using replace() method.

For example, When I'm accessing /page1, it is save in the history. 'centre' parameter is added automatically with replace() so it doesn't add a new history entry:

```
$location.search('centre', hash).replace();
```

Every time I move a map, 'centre' changes.

When I go to /page2, the new entry in the history is created. When I move map, 'centre' changes.

The thing is that when I press BACK button, I'm going to /page1 but I need to keep 'centre' the same as it was before, but it changes to what was saved together with history entry of /page1.

How would I fix this issue?

I tried to add:

```
$window.history.replaceState({}, '', $location.absUrl());
```

After I do replace(), but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found calling the search & replace inside a 0ms timeout ensures it happens in a separate digest cycle from the main state change and prevents the previous state being replaced.

Something like:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $location.search('centre', hash).replace();
}, 0);
```

Comment: No need for a digest call unless called outside an angular digest, the replace method sets a flag to replace the history inside angular during the current digest cycle and will update to false after the digest is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this.

First, we need to save search result as previous and current:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, toURL, fromURL) {
    if ($rootScope.search.current) {
        $rootScope.search.previous = $rootScope.search.current;
    }

    $rootScope.search.current = $location.search();
});
```

Then we need to always change the actual location we are in at the moment.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, toURL, fromURL) {
    $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
});
```

And if back of forward button was pressed, center must be changed in the URL (using previous search results) without pushing a new history entry.

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () { return $location.path() }, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
    if ($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
        $location.search('center', $rootScope.search.previous.center).replace();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and could only get it working by using the native history api, like so:

```
window.history.replaceState(hash, null, $location.absUrl());
```

Comment: The digest cycle will load the page